# Copying mutiple Excel sheets of different workbook into a single workbook

Tags: java, apache-poi

Problem: How to copy multiple Excel sheets of different workbook into a single workbook not by cell by cell copying as it makes performance issues as I have large data in sheets.Is there any option to copy whole sheets without iterating over every cell using Java. Just copy the whole sheets into other.

Answer (score 1):

This below will copy every worksheet from a workbook you set. I will copy it and paste it at the end of the list of sheets on your current workbook

```
Sub CopyWorkbook()

Dim sh as Worksheet,  wb as workbook

Set wb = workbooks("Target workbook")
For Each sh in workbooks("source workbook").Worksheets
   sh.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.sheets.count) 
Next sh

End Sub
```

Comment: If you aren't wanting to use VBA, I think you should remove the VBA tag